# multi dimensional arrays using PHP

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

Im new with using php and is wondering how to output a muilti dimentional array. Here is my test code:

```
<html>
<body>
<p>
   <?php
      $test2 = array(
           array("!","#","#"),
       array("@","!","#"),
       array("@","@","!",)  
      );

     echo $test2[0][0]."-".$test2[0][1]."-".$test2[0][2]."<br>";
     echo $test2[1][0]."-".$test2[1][1]."-".$test2[1][2]."<br>";
     echo $test2[2][0]."-".$test2[2][1]."-".$test2[2][2]."<br>";
     echo  "<br>";

     for($f=0; $f < count($test2); $f++)
     {
        for($g=0; $g < count($test2); $g++)
        {
           echo "<br>$test2[$f][$g] - ";
        }
     }
   ?>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

whenever i test this i get the error "Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\wamp\www\Test.php"

Comment: Does the notice give a line number of the issue?

Comment: What are you trying to print?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't toss an array into a double-quoted string like that. It'll break on at `$test2`. (That is, it thinks you want to say, literally, (Array converted to string)[0][2].)

Valid solutions:

A. Put your variable in curly braces, which will cause PHP to parse that whole bit as a variable.

```
<?php
  $test2 = array(
       array("!","#","#"),
   array("@","!","#"),
   array("@","@","!",)  
  );

 echo $test2[0][0]."-".$test2[0][1]."-".$test2[0][2]."<br>";
 echo $test2[1][0]."-".$test2[1][1]."-".$test2[1][2]."<br>";
 echo $test2[2][0]."-".$test2[2][1]."-".$test2[2][2]."<br>";
 echo  "<br>";

 for($f=0; $f < count($test2); $f++)
 {
    for($g=0; $g < count($test2); $g++)
    {
       echo "<br>{$test2[$f][$g]} - ";
    }
 }
```

B. Use concatentation.

```
<?php
  $test2 = array(
       array("!","#","#"),
   array("@","!","#"),
   array("@","@","!",)  
  );

 echo $test2[0][0]."-".$test2[0][1]."-".$test2[0][2]."<br>";
 echo $test2[1][0]."-".$test2[1][1]."-".$test2[1][2]."<br>";
 echo $test2[2][0]."-".$test2[2][1]."-".$test2[2][2]."<br>";
 echo  "<br>";

 for($f=0; $f < count($test2); $f++)
 {
    for($g=0; $g < count($test2); $g++)
    {
       echo "<br>" . $test2[$f][$g] . " - ";
    }
 }
```

C. Use a foreach() loop instead of a for() loop.

```
<?php
  $test2 = array(
       array("!","#","#"),
   array("@","!","#"),
   array("@","@","!",)  
  );

 echo $test2[0][0]."-".$test2[0][1]."-".$test2[0][2]."<br>";
 echo $test2[1][0]."-".$test2[1][1]."-".$test2[1][2]."<br>";
 echo $test2[2][0]."-".$test2[2][1]."-".$test2[2][2]."<br>";
 echo  "<br>";

 foreach($test2 as $inner_array)
 {
    foreach($inner_array as $item)
    {
       echo "<br>$item - ";
    }
 }
```

I usually use concatenation myself so it's very easy to see the variables when glancing at the code, but failing that, you should always put your variables in curly braces to avoid confusion. This is also important if you wanted to pluralize something... `{$item}s` would print out `$item` and append an s.

A foreach() loop probably makes more sense here though (I would also put the braces around the variable, which I didn't show in my code.)

Comment: Also, as @Sutandiono pointed out below, if you do end up going with the for() loop, your inner for() loop should be counting the inner array... `count($test2[$f])`

Answer (score 0):

You should not echo manually chosen arrays:

```
<?php
$test2 = array(
    array("!","#","#"),
    array("@","!","#"),
    array("@","@","!",)  
);

echo $test2[0][0]."-".$test2[0][1]."-".$test2[0][2]."<br>";
echo $test2[1][0]."-".$test2[1][1]."-".$test2[1][2]."<br>";
echo $test2[2][0]."-".$test2[2][1]."-".$test2[2][2]."<br>";
echo  "<br>";

for($f = 0; $f < count($test2); $f++) {
    for($g = 0; $g < count($test2[$f]); $g++) {
        $value = $test2[$f][$g];
        echo "{$value} - ";
    }
    echo '<br />';
}
```

or you may also try using [foreach](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

```
<?php
$test2 = array(
    array("!","#","#"),
    array("@","!","#"),
    array("@","@","!",)  
);

echo $test2[0][0]."-".$test2[0][1]."-".$test2[0][2]."<br>";
echo $test2[1][0]."-".$test2[1][1]."-".$test2[1][2]."<br>";
echo $test2[2][0]."-".$test2[2][1]."-".$test2[2][2]."<br>";
echo  "<br>";

//--> First foreach for extracting sub arrays
foreach($test2 as $test1) {
    //--> Second foreach for extracting values of sub arrays
    foreach($test1 as $test) {
        echo "{$test} - ";
    }
    echo '<br />';
}
```

and lastly, the lazy aproach:
you may also try making a function that will print any values just for output:

```
function io($a = 0) {
   echo '<pre>';
      print_r($a);
   echo '</pre>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're facing is within your two loops:

```
for($f=0; $f < count($test2); $f++)
{
    for($g=0; $g < count($test2[$f]); $g++)
    {
       echo "<br>$test2[$f][$g] - ";
    }
}
```

Embedding variables within double quoted strings is no problem, but if they are complex you'll have to enclose them in braces. The reason is simple, look how PHP will interpret your string after the echo if you use single quotes for the same statement.

```
echo '<br>' , $test2 , '[' , $f , '][' , $g , '] - ';
```

### Correct Way

```
for($f=0; $f < count($test2); $f++)
{
    for($g=0; $g < count($test2[$f]); $g++)
    {
       echo "<br>{$test2[$f][$g]} - ";
    }
}
```

*PS:* Of course there is no correct way. I refer with this phrase to *what you wanted to achieve with your original code*.

Comment: Also for the inner loop, you need to `count ($test2[$f])` instead of `count ($test2)`, since the later will use the size of outer loop. But of course, best if you can assign the `count()` to a variable instead of doing the count with each loop.

Comment: Many thanks, absolutely right. `sizeof()` would be another alternative if you want to get the last µs out of it (lol).

Answer (score 0):

You need to seperate your array from the rest of the string in the loops. There are two ways to do this:

```
echo "<br>{$test2[$f][$g]} - ";
```

Or

```
echo "<br>".$test2[$f][$g]." - ";
```

Right now, it is trying to print $test2, then $f, then $g. $test2 is giving the error.

Answer (score -1):

You can use **print_r ($test2 )** to take your desired output.in your loop.